# Open a port in iptables for limited time, and close it without severing existing connections

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I want to open a port in mi firewall for a limited time, let's say 22, and shut it down after few minutes (so that connections from other IPs rather than the one is currently established will find the port closed). So far, this is what I have come with:

a) Have a permanent rule in iptables stating to keep alive existing connections

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

b) Add a rule in iptables allowing connections from specific IP to connect, and remove it after some time:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
```

Is this supposed to work, or there is something wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Compare [port knocking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Port_knocking). Maybe it will fit your needs even better.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: That's a different part of the equation... port knocking is only a mechanism of adding the IP-based rule, but it's still the exact same firewall that ends up allowing/filtering packets in the end.

Comment: @grawity I did not address the "non-different" part. :) My previous comment may have been "Maybe this mechanism of adding the IP-based rule will fit your needs even better."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all TCP packets will be matched by `--state ESTABLISHED` as long as conntrack does not forget the corresponding state entry. Make sure the server's conntrack timeouts are sufficiently long (you can find them in the `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established` sysctl – the default is 5 days but some systems change it to *very* short timeouts).

(You should actually accept established/related ICMP packets as well, to let the server receive things like Path MTU discovery packets and other ICMP error packets.)

You can use an [*ipset*](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html) for matching new IP addresses – it has a timeout feature built in.

Comment: Right, at the end I went for an nft solution (ipset was not installed and I see Debian is moving to nft, so I gave a try): nft add set ip filter SSHallowed { type ipv4_addr\; timeout 2m \;} + nft insert rule ip filter INPUT ip saddr @SSHallowed tcp dport 22 accept + nft add element ip filter SSHallowed { XX.XX.XX.XX }